# Programmatically backup a SQL Server database without it being logged/included in the backup history

Tags: c#, sql-server

I create backups from a MS SQL Server Instance in a C# program I developed.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"BACKUP DATABASE [{base1C.SqlDbName}] TO 
DISK = N'{tp}' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'{archiveFileName}', NOSKIP, 
REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, CHECKSUM", connect) {CommandTimeout = 0};
```

SQL Server remembers backups that are created.  How do I create a backup that is not recorded and will not affect other backups or the transaction log?

Comment: Sounds like you’re trying to do a copy only backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for a "copy-only backup" - check out the [Microsoft Docs on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

So basically just add a `COPY_ONLY` option to your backup command (in the `WITH` section):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"BACKUP DATABASE [{base1C.SqlDbName}] TO 
DISK = N'{tp}' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'{archiveFileName}', NOSKIP, 
REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, CHECKSUM, COPY_ONLY", connect) {CommandTimeout = 0};
```

Comment: Thanks all, it is what i need.